# Sending files and data between client and server using Sockets in C

Tags: c, network-programming

I am trying to do a couple functions using the following two scripts. I am trying to upload files from client to server, download files from server to client, changing the directory of the server and then downloading the list of files in that directory from the server to the client.

When I run my current scripts, I am able to input the file name to upload but it doesnt upload and goes straight to the next function (to download a file). If i specify the file to download, it get stuck.

I assume that my issue is in the way that sockets are accepting and closing the socket once the action is performed but I am not sure how to go about it. I have included both my server and client code below. Keep in mind that the socket creation, binding and listening are all working correctly.

client.c

```
/* A simple echo client using TCP */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>


#define SERVER_TCP_PORT 3000    /* well-known port */
#define BUFLEN 256  /* buffer length */
#define sendrecvflag 0
#define cipherKey 'S' 


// function to clear buffer 
void clearBuf(char* b) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < BUFLEN; i++) 
        b[i] = '\0'; 
} 

// function for decryption 
char Cipher(char ch) 
{ 
    return ch ^ cipherKey; 
} 

// function to receive file 
int recvFile(char* buf, int s) 
{ 
    int i; 
    char ch; 
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++) { 
        ch = buf[i]; 
        ch = Cipher(ch); 
        if (ch == EOF) 
            return 1; 
        else
            printf("%c", ch); 
    } 
    return 0; 
} 


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     n, i, bytes_to_read, b, nBytes;
    int     sockfd, port;
    struct  hostent     *hp;
    struct  sockaddr_in server;
    char    *host, *bp, net_buf[BUFLEN], input[20];
        int addrlen = sizeof(server);

    switch(argc){
    case 2:
        host = argv[1];
        port = SERVER_TCP_PORT;
        break;
    case 3:
        host = argv[1];
        port = atoi(argv[2]);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s host [port]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create a stream socket   */  
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't creat a socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Bind an address to the socket    */
    bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (hp = gethostbyname(host)) 
      bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&server.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    else if ( inet_aton(host, (struct in_addr *) &server.sin_addr) ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't get server's address\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    /* Connecting to the server */
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, addrlen) == -1){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't connect \n");
      exit(1);
    }

    while(1){

        //This is for file upload--------------
        printf("Specify file to upload:");
        scanf("%s", &input);

        //need to create this file in the file system.
        FILE *fp = fopen(input, "rb");

        if(fp == NULL){
            perror("File doesnt exist");
            return 2;
        }

        while( (b = fread(net_buf, 1, sizeof(net_buf), fp))>0 ){
            send(sockfd, net_buf, b, sendrecvflag);
        }
        printf("done sending content");
        fclose(fp);

        //This is for file download---------------
        printf("Specify the file that you want to download from server:");
        scanf("%s", net_buf);

        sendto(sockfd, net_buf, BUFLEN, 
                sendrecvflag, (struct sockaddr*)&server, 
                addrlen);

        printf("\n---------Data Received---------\n"); 
        while(1){
            // receive 
                clearBuf(net_buf); 

                nBytes = recvfrom(sockfd, net_buf, BUFLEN, 
                        sendrecvflag, (struct sockaddr*)&server,
                        &addrlen);


                // process 
                if (recvFile(net_buf, BUFLEN)) { 
                    break; 
                } 
        }

        //This is for Change in directory
        printf("Specify the directory you want to change to: ");
        scanf("%s", net_buf);
        sendto(sockfd, net_buf, BUFLEN, 
               sendrecvflag, (struct sockaddr*)&server, 
               addrlen);

        printf("\n---------Directory Has been Changed---------\n"); 


        //This is for Listing directory
        printf("Specify the directory(ex.'.'): ");
        scanf("%s", net_buf);

        sendto(sockfd, net_buf, BUFLEN, 
               sendrecvflag, (struct sockaddr*)&server, 
               addrlen);

        printf("\n---------Directory Data Received---------\n"); 

        while(1){
            // receive 
                clearBuf(net_buf); 

                nBytes = recvfrom(sockfd, net_buf, BUFLEN, 
                                    sendrecvflag, (struct sockaddr*)&server,
                                    &addrlen);


                // process 
                if (recvFile(net_buf, BUFLEN)) { 
                    break; 
                } 
        }
        //End
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return(0);
}
```

server.c

```
/* A simple echo server using TCP */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERVER_TCP_PORT 3000    /* well-known port */
#define BUFLEN 256  /* buffer length */
#define cipherKey 'S' 
#define nofile "File Not Found!" 
#define sendrecvflag 0

int echod(int);
void reaper(int);


// function to clear buffer 
void clearBuf(char* b) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < BUFLEN; i++) 
        b[i] = '\0'; 
} 


// function for decryption 
char Cipher(char ch) 
{ 
    return ch ^ cipherKey; 
} 


// function sending file 
int sendFile(FILE* fp, char* buf, int s) 
{ 
    int i, len; 
    if (fp == NULL) { 
        strcpy(buf, nofile); 
        len = strlen(nofile); 
        buf[len] = EOF; 
        for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) 
            buf[i] = Cipher(buf[i]); 
        return 1; 
    } 

    char ch, ch2; 
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++) { 
        ch = fgetc(fp); 
        ch2 = Cipher(ch); 
        buf[i] = ch2; 
        if (ch == EOF) 
            return 1; 
    } 
    return 0; 
} 


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     sockfd, new_sd, client_len, port, confd = 0,b,tot, nBytes;
    struct  sockaddr_in server, client;
    char net_buf[BUFLEN];
    int addrlen = sizeof(server);

    switch(argc){
    case 1:
        port = SERVER_TCP_PORT;
        break;
    case 2:
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %d [port]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create a stream socket   */  
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't creat a socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Bind an address to the socket    */
    bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, addrlen) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't bind name to socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    if(listen(sockfd, 10) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }



    while(1) {

      //This is for file upload
      printf("This is sending file");
      confd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
        if (confd==-1) {
            perror("Accept");
            continue;
        }
        //Should create a text file.
        FILE* fp = fopen( "test.txt", "wb");
        tot=0;

        if(fp != NULL){
            while( (b = recv(confd, net_buf, BUFLEN,sendrecvflag))> 0 ) {
                tot+=b;
                fwrite(net_buf, 1, b, fp);
            }

            printf("Received byte: %d\n",tot);
            if (b<0)
               perror("Error recieving the file");

            fclose(fp);
        } else {
            perror("File doesnt exist");
        }

    close(confd);

        //This is for file download
        printf("\nWaiting for file name...\n");
        confd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
        if (confd==-1){
        perror("Accept");
        continue;
        }

        // receive file name 
        clearBuf(net_buf); 

        nBytes = recvfrom(sockfd, net_buf, 
                          BUFLEN, sendrecvflag, 
                          (struct sockaddr *)&server, &addrlen);

        fp = fopen(net_buf, "r");

        printf("\nFile Name Received: %s\n", net_buf); 
        if (fp == NULL) 
            printf("\nFile open failed!\n"); 
        else
            printf("\nFile Successfully opened!\n"); 


        while (1) { 

            // process 
            if (sendFile(fp, net_buf, BUFLEN)) { 
                sendto(sockfd, net_buf, BUFLEN, 
                       sendrecvflag,  
                    (struct sockaddr*)&server, addrlen); 
                break; 
            } 

            // send 
            sendto(sockfd, net_buf, BUFLEN, 
                   sendrecvflag, 
                (struct sockaddr*)&server, addrlen); 
            clearBuf(net_buf); 
        } 
        if (fp != NULL) 
            fclose(fp); 

        //This is for Change in directory
        clearBuf(net_buf);
        nBytes = recvfrom(sockfd, net_buf, 
                          BUFLEN, sendrecvflag, 
                          (struct sockaddr*)&server, &addrlen);
        chdir(net_buf);


        //This is for Listing directory
        clearBuf(net_buf); 
        nBytes = recvfrom(sockfd, net_buf, 
                          BUFLEN, sendrecvflag, 
                          (struct sockaddr*)&server, &addrlen);
        DIR *d;
        struct dirent *dir;
        d = opendir(net_buf);
        if (d){
                while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
                {
                    // send 
                    strcpy(net_buf,dir->d_name );
                    sendto(sockfd, net_buf, BUFLEN, 
                        sendrecvflag, 
                        (struct sockaddr*)&server, addrlen); 
                    clearBuf(net_buf);
                }
                closedir(d);
        }else{
            printf("File Directory doesnt exist");
        }
        //End
    }
}
```

I have functions that encrypt and send the data in both. This is not necessary but I wanted to understand encryption on a very high level. The main code starts after the first while loop. There is not a lot of code. One last thing to mention is that the IP and port number are sent as argument, again this isnt something that needs attention since the connection is successful.

Comment: `bcopy()` is deprecated, you should use `memcpy()`.

Comment: And `bzero()` should be replaced with `memset()`.

Comment: You should use `perror()` when reporting errors, so you see the reason.

Comment: Why are you using `sendto` and `recvfrom` with a TCP connection?

Comment: `input` gives the address :  `scanf("%s", input);`

Comment: As for a possible problem, in the server you receive the file the client send, and then it closes the connection. If it want to continue with the communication it needs to keep the connection open.

Comment: The server expects the socket to be closed when the upload is completed. The client doesn't close the socket, it sends the change directory name and then the directory to list. The server will view this as part of the upload file.